# Adding layer in ArcScene using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcscene

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"F:\project\Final\Ground floor\steps.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
```

this code is for adding a layer in arcmap. when i use the same code to add a 3D layer in arcscene i get the following error

```
cannot open map document

Failed to execute (addlayer).
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, ArcScene has not been opened up to ArcPy like ArcMap has.

There is an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000004VV7IAM) to have this functionality added to which you might like to add your name.

Alternatively, keep an eye on ArcGIS Pro because its ArcPy has a [Camera](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/camera-class.htm) class designed for 3D:

> The Camera object provides access to 2D and 3D viewer properties that
>   control the display in a MapFrame.